# How to get the Google Meet link from Google Classroom with python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-classroom

I would like to retrieve the google meet links that are in the banners of some of the classes in my classroom and check if they are active. I checked the API for classroom but I didn't find anything there.

this is what the meet link looks like:
[image]

Comment: "google meet links that are in the banners of some of the classes" could you post a screenshot to illustrate what you mean? If it has sensitive info remove it first. Thank you!

Comment: @Aerials I have updated the question and added a screenshot of it

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an API method to get this link yet. I did a quick search in Google's Issue Tracker and found there is a recent request from developers to get this ink via the API. You should (and anyone else interested) star the issue so it gets more visibility from Google.

Here's the link to the feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156772382